# How can I make multiple projects share node_modules directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I make projects, I have to download all dependencies of node modules. Without copying the node_modules, Is there anyway to share the central node_modules in multiple projects?

like the followings, I have to run many commands every time..

```
npm install gulp-usemin                                                                        
npm install gulp-wrap
npm install gulp-connect
npm install gulp-watch
npm install gulp-minify-css
npm install gulp-uglify
npm install gulp-concat
npm install gulp-less
npm install gulp-rename
npm install gulp-minify-html
```

Comment: You can install them in a common, parent directory, if there is one. Node will [walk up the directories](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) searching for the `require`d module. Otherwise, no, there isn't an official "central" `node_modules` folder for use with `require()`.

Comment: You can globally install these packages by using global flag. So you do not need to run install commands every time. `npm install <npm_package_name> -g`

Comment: In Sveltekit, it's simple that you just need to put it like this: build file `./../build` and `./node_modules`.

Answer (score 126):

You absolutely can share a node_modules directory amongst projects.

From **[node's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)**:

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module,
>   and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then node starts at the
>   parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and
>   attempts to load the module from that location.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and
>   so on, until the root of the file system is reached.
>
> For example, if the file at '/home/ry/projects/foo.js' called
>   require('bar.js'), then node would look in the following locations, in
>   this order:
>
> /home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js /home/ry/node_modules/bar.js
>   /home/node_modules/bar.js /node_modules/bar.js

So just put a node_modules folder inside your projects directory and put in whatever modules you want.  Just require them like normal.  When node doesn't find a node_modules directory in your project folder, it will check the parent folder automatically.  So make your directory structure like this:

```
-myProjects
--node_modules
--myproject1
---sub-project
--myproject2
```

So like this, even your sub-project's dependencies can draw on your main node_modules repository.

One drawback to doing it this way is you will have to build out your package.json file manually (unless someone knows a way to automate this with grunt or something).  When you install your packages and add the --save arg to an `npm install` command it automatically appends it to the dependencies section or your package.json, which is convenient.

Comment: Why isn't this accepted as an answer op? Further question to @tpie, should one structure a project like you suggested, how would one build the package.json to install from the parent module repository.

Comment: @diehell So it seems that it's "all or nothing". If all or dependencies live in a parent directory and there is no node_modules directory in the CWD then npm will check the parent and install there if it finds it. If you put a node_modules folder in the directory it will install there.

Comment: I don't see how sharing node_modules can handle different package versions, the packages in node_modules are not versioned, unlike the npm-cache in c:\users (Windows), did anyone run into that?

Comment: How would I modify my paradigm when writing npm scripts, and package.json files?

Comment: I get this error "Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?"

Answer (score 43):

Try [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) instead of npm.

> pnpm uses hard links and symlinks to save one version of a module only ever once on a disk.

If you have npm installed, you can install in your terminal with:

```
npm install -g pnpm
```

To update your existing installations (and sub-directories) use:

```
pnpm recursive install
```

*Or use the shorthand command (leave off `-r` if you need to target only one directory)*

```
pnpm -r i
```

**One helpful note:** You may find some rare packages don't have all their dependencies defined. They might rely on the flat `node_modules` file directory structure of npm or yarn installs. If you run into issues of missing dependencies,  use this command to hoist all the sub dependencies into a flat-file structure:

```
pnpm install --shamefully-hoist
```

It's best to avoid using the `--shamefully-hoist` flag as it defeats the purpose of using pnpm in the first place, so try using the command `pnpm i your-missing-package` first (See [pnpm FAQ](https://pnpm.io/faq#pnpm-does-not-work-with-your-project-here)).

Comment: A WORD OF WARNING: pnpm is notoriously unstable. It can't reliably do things as basic as *updating itself*, and it WILL pester you to update 3 times a week on average. As of Aug 2021, it has 500+ open issues on github.

Comment: +1 for `pnpm` ! I keep my project folders in my Dropbox folder for backup purposes. But I did not want all the thousands of files of the node_modules folder also backed up. Also wanted to avoid having multiple copies of npm packages in many places. With pnpm I could set up one folder outside of Dropbox for all npm packages while still having project specific, separate package.json files. The folders and files in the project's node_modules folder contain only symlinks which Dropbox doesn't follow. So for me, it's the best solution! (so far)

Comment: pnmp messed up all my projects. I had to remove them and copy the files again. It has 850 open issues on github!

Answer (score 27):

I found a trick, just take a look at the [Symbolic Links (symlinks) on Windows or Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), it is working just like shortcuts but more powerful.

Simply you need to make a [`Junction`](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) for your `node_modules` folder anywhere you want. The junction is nothing but a short cut to your original node_modules folder. Create it inside your project folder where the actual node_modules would have been created if used `npm install`.

To achieve this you need at least one `node_modules` real folder then make a Junction to it in the other projects.

On Windows, you can either use the Command Prompt, or use an application. Using the Command Prompt gives you a bit more control, using an application is easier I suggest [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html).

Comment: I cd to target dir, run this command: `mklink /d node_modules (source dir)\node_modules`.

Comment: My team has been using this method for some time now. While I really despise not having `node_modules` in the project folder itself, this works. Just gotta remember to browse to the actual `node_modules` folder before installing anything new :P

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work for me. When I use either symbolic or junctions, I get the following error with node-sass:Module build failed: "Error: Module did not self-register" and the error has further details specifying the directory where the "shared" node_modules directory exists. Any ideas?

Comment: How to avoid dependency pruning when running `npm install` in any of the "connected" apps?

Comment: This thing works very good. For other methods my npm scripts did't work but it works for this.

Comment: but when I run `npm install <new-package>` all the packages not in your current project's package.json are removed.

Answer (score 19):

Main directory should look like this

```
node_modules
Project 1
Project 2
Project 3
Project 4
```

just open the file `Project 1/.angular-cli.json`

change the schema

```
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
```

to

```
"$schema": "./../node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json"
```

and don't forget to create `node_modules` empty folder inside your project directory

Comment: You are my hero. I have spent a *week* on this. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 9):

See also npm v7.0.0's support for workspaces

RFC
https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0026-workspaces.md

Documentation
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces

Comment: In 2021, it looks like this is the best way to go now.

Answer (score 5):

By looking at some articles it seems that [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/)
is a good tool for managing multiple projects inside a single directory (`monorepo`). It supports modules sharing without duplicating the entire packages in every folder and commands to install them in multiple projects.

- [Javascript monorepos](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/02/23/javascript-monorepos.html)
- [Monorepos by example](https://codeburst.io/monorepos-by-example-part-1-3a883b49047e)
- [Building large scale apps in a monorepo](https://medium.com/@luisvieira_gmr/building-large-scale-react-applications-in-a-monorepo-91cd4637c131)

[pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/) is also a simple and efficient tool, which doesn't duplicate those modules which are already installed for other projects.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that having a single node_modules it should contain all the packages for all applications. thus your apps will also share most of the unique package.json entries (just the name should change)

my idea would be to have a single root and multiple src level as below

```
root\package.json
root\node_modules
root\\..
root\app1\src\\..
root\app2\src\\..
```

the only issue you might face would be having a backup of json (or tsconfig) for any app and restore them when you work on it or setup your startup scripts to serve any app