# Setting up multiple local projects with Semantic-UI

Tags: semantic-ui

I seem to be quite confused with how this works. I've installed Semantic-UI with one site and it has it's own "semantic" folder, but when I try to install Semantic again using Gulp, it says that it is already installed. True, it is installed within that specific project.

Should I have given semantic it's own folder within my "Sites" folder, and then referenced specific themes within each project?

Any information on how to set up semantic UI locally for multiple websites is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to share the semantic-ui directory that is in the node_modules directory with multiple projects?

Comment: Sharing would be preferred, if there is a way.

Comment: Take a look here then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29787493/5192503