# How to create a new project in angular offline?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

While creating a new project in Angular, it always needs an internet connection to download packages. This also takes much time here.

As I understand, the packages are pretty standard, so if one project is created; there should be provision to take it from repo created earlier.

Is there a way to create a project offline?

The command I use to create a new project is `ng new <project name>`

Comment: I believe you can consider [setting up local npm repository](https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/)

Comment: If you use yarn, you can setup an [offline mirror](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the angular CLI you can use `--skip-install` flag so you can skip installing all the NPM packages.

So basically, you can create a new project using the following command:

`ng new yourProject --skip-install`

Comment: But this will anyways ask for npm-install. My question is; is there a way to point to already installed packages or shall I xcopy modules in this newly created app?

Answer (score 11):

Following steps can be used to create the ng project offline.

1- First create only the project structure skipping additional installtions

```
/> ng new ProjectName  --skip-install  (Use –skip-npm in older version. also you can use --skip-install=true )
```

2- Copy the **node_modules** folder from an existing project and paste inside your newly created project

3- Only pasting the dependencies is not sufficient. For the configurations to take effect run below command inside your project folder.

```
/> npm install
```

Please note that I had disabled the internet connection to check the dependencies were not downloaded from internet again (~284 MB).

[image]

4- You can see the message like "added 70 packages, removed 263 packages, updated 94 packages and moved 12 packages in 111.811s". You are done. Check the project is running in the browser after executing command:

```
/> ng serve
```

**Update: Another way to re-use "ng_modules" like shared library**

I found another way to [reuse ng_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786887/how-can-i-make-multiple-projects-share-node-modules-directory/37572003#37572003). By creating a junction (symbolic link of existing ng_modules inside the new project, we don't have to copy paste this folder.). But this approach has its own disadvantage as its always good to keep all stuff related to one project at one place. So use this for small dev/testing projects only.

Comment: Why is this not the answer?

Answer (score 2):

1- You can create an Angular project with `ng new testOffline  --skip-install`

2- Inside the project directory Install the offline version of node modules with `npm install --prefer-offline --no-audit`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this problem with recent npm releases. Npm caches installed packages, running `ng new OnlineProject` once with internet access will allow `ng new OfflineProject` to finish successfully offline. This should also work with packages beeing installed with `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

copy the resources from another project, if you want to save space. Copy the Node modules that you are going to use in the project. Done

Comment: it must be a blank project.. if not, you will have to edit it, of course