# How to reference node_modules in the parent directory that makes up a project in angular4

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, package.json

I do not speak English very well.

My current directory configuration

[image]

```
Project
├ node_modules
├ packages
│ ├ product
│ │ ├ dashboard   => don't have "node_modules" directory
│ │ │ ├ package.json
│ │ │ ...
│ │ ...
│ ...
├ package.json
...
```

and **dashboard directory package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --dev --hmr --port 8460 -pc proxy.conf.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod -aot -sm",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.26",
    "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.2"
  }
}
```

and my **Project directory package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo 'Error: no test specified' && exit 1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
        "core-js": "^2.5.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.3.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.6",
        "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.6",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.54",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.26",
        "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^1.7.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "^5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
        "tslint": "^5.7.0",
        "typescript": "^2.5.2"
    }
}
```

above package.json files are not special

I have updated the packages in dependencies in the package.json file generated by angular-cli

I want refer to the **node_modules** of the top-level folder **Project** in the package.json file of the **dashboard directory**

but

Running the **npm run build** command from the **dashboard directory** will result in the error

[image]

My WARN message says that **node_modules** can not be found

I'm finded this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787493/6637745)

But, like the links's answer, My Project does not seem to work.

I think it might be a problem with typescript. 
But I do not know exactly where the problem is.

Can you help me?

Comment: Thank you for posting the question in English. While I don't have a different answer from the one you found, [learning English as a programmer is very useful](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ugly-american-programmer/).

Comment: @DanDascalescu Thank you for your teaching. I'm currently studying english and will do it in the future. But English is to hard 