# jhipster node modules folder is created within the project folder

Tags: jhipster

I am trying out a sample application in jhispter

When I type the "jhispter" command . I got a set of questions and then the project was successfully created

Within the project folder , there is a folder "node_modules" . This has lots of folders which were download when I ran the jhipster command . There are also lots of other files like tsconfig.json , proxy.conf.json etc , under the project directory

Ideally within the project folder ,I would like to have only  **src**  folder and **pom.xml**/**gradle.build** files which I will check into my source code control.

Is it possible to create the node_module in a different path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, node_modules contains the angular/typescript tools and your app dependencies, it is included in `.gitignore` file it won't be committed into your git repository. This is how npm/yarn work: a global node_modules and a local node_modules. This is just different from what you are used to with mvn/gradle.

Regarding other config files (tsconfig.json, etc...), you can always move them around but I would advise against doing so as you seem to discover frontend tooling and also you won't be able to upgrade easily JHipster for your project using `jhipster upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification .

Comment: So are you telling me that with every new application you generate with JHipster, you have to download an almost 500MB node_modules folder? Wow this seems inefficient. Surely there is a way for all your JHipster projects to share a common node_modules folder ?

Comment: This is how npm works, nothing related to JHipster.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786887/how-can-i-make-multiple-projects-share-node-modules-directory for workarounds