# How to share node modules between vue-cli 3 app?

Tags: node-modules, vue-cli-3

Does anyone know how to specify the NODE_PATH for a vue-cli app? I've tried setting a NODE_PATH environment variable from within my app folder but no luck.

My goal is to move the node_modules folder a couple of directories up as I will be using multiple vue-cli apps and would like to reuse the 180M worth of code for each app!

I've also tried setting the NODE_PATH in package.json but still no luck.

My understanding is that node will look for the modules in the parent directory but it is not working. If someone has a working example with vue-cli specifically, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make multiple projects share node\_modules directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786887/how-can-i-make-multiple-projects-share-node-modules-directory)

Comment: I've updated my question. When I try to run `npm run serve`, it complains that it cannot find vue cli service, which is in the node_modules folder.

Comment: This person gives 3 different links to doing a monorepo which is what it seems like you are trying to do...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335001/592831   Is installing globally an option? when you run an `npm install`, where do the node_modules end up?

Comment: @AndyDangerGagne I'll go through these articles and see if I can get it working with my vue-cli apps, thanks. Yes, installing globally is fine. When I run npm install the node modules folder gets created at the current folder I am in.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working however I'm not sure if is a best practice. Seems like `vue-cli` needs a local package to initialize.

So I placed a copy of the `node_modules` folder in the parent directory and deleted all the packages from my app's `node_modules` folder, except for the `@vue` folder and the hidden `.bin` folder.

Vue uses the local `vue-cli` package to initialize and then traverses up to the parent folder when it can't find the other dependencies.

This now allows me to have multiple `vue-cli` apps reusing a single set of default packages. If any of my apps need additional dependencies, I will just install them locally, per app.