# How to corerctly distribute node_modules for nodejs typescript project with microservices

Tags: node.js, typescript

If I have a project with smaller projects in it , and the smaller projects use packages from the main package.json , when I want to build one of the smaller projects ( as a microservice )  do I have to copy the whole node_modules directory from the parent into the distribution directory?  Or can I somehow just build the ones I want?    Is this a good way of developing?

```
main
 -- package.json  ( contains all packages used by all projects )
 -- tsconfig.json  ( contains project references for sub projects )
 -- node_modules
 -- subproject1
    -- package.json ( contains only run scripts )
    -- tsconfig.json
 -- subproject2
    -- package.json ( contains only run scripts )
    -- tsconfig.json (edited)
```

Comment: You should using the subproject-level package.json manifests to list the dependencies for each subproject. That way, each one acts as a source of truth for each subproject, and each subproject will only install the dependencies it needs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make multiple projects share node\_modules directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786887/how-can-i-make-multiple-projects-share-node-modules-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea of having separate package.json and tsconfig.js files for each subproject. Because,

- Easier to manage each sub project
- End of the day, if you are deploying the subproject as different micro services, each micro service can define what they use
- Easier to make the subproject as separate git projects in the future

Also those are `micro services`, they should

- only do what they suppose to do
- only install what they need