# Can I put applications on same folder level as workspace in Angular?

Tags: angular, monorepo, nrwl

I'm trying to create a few application using [Workspace](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects) in Angular 8, and I'm wondering whether is possible to have such folder strucuture:

```
|/Myproj
       |/Workspace
       |
       |/Application_1
       |
       |/Application_2
```

Everywhere in tutorials, folders with applications are inside `Workspace/projects` but for some reason I'd like to have it on same level, thus next to workspace directly inside `Myproj` folder. I was trying to update all paths in configurations in `Workspace/angular.json` eg. from this `"root": "projects/Application_1",` to this `"root": "../Application_1",`. But all the time whilst building (`ng build --project=Application_1`) I have some errors eg. `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot locate node_modules directory.`.

And I wonder if this is possible at all? Or I shouldn't waste my time because this is how it works and no way to change it. Also I was trying to find some solution with [NRWL](https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/what-is-nx) but without any success.

Comment: What would be in the `Workspace` folder, if your applications are in the root of `Myproj`?

Comment: `Workspace`'s files. Angular.json, node_modules, tsconfig.json etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Without understanding exactly why you want to move things around, I don't believe your approach will work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786887/how-can-i-make-multiple-projects-share-node-modules-directory#answer-29787493) for how node locates the node_modules directory. If it's not found in root, it will search parent directories, not child directories. It sounds like you want to have angular.json and node_modules in Workspace (child directory), which is problematic.

If you don't like how deeply nested things currently are, could you just move *the entire Angular workspace* one level up (basically get rid Workspace and have Myproj be the new workspace root)?

**Old answer for simply moving a project to a different directory in your workspace**

NX user here. It's definitely possible, but I can't recommend you do this. There is a ton of value in having at least the one level of organization between `apps` and `libs`, especially as your monorepo grows.

But if you're set on doing this, I've listed the files and properties below that you'll need to update in an NX monorepo. The idea is the same for a plain angular workspace, you'll need to modify file paths in more than just `angular.json`.

*Note: do not replace an absolute path with a relative path. `apps/my-app` becomes `my-app` NOT `../my-app`*

### **angular.json configuration for my-app**

- Update the **absolute paths** for the following properties:

  - `root`
  - `sourceRoot`
  - `architect.build.options.outputPath`
  - `architect.build.options.index`
  - `architect.build.options.main`
  - `architect.build.options.polyfills`
  - `architect.build.options.tsConfig`
  - `architect.build.options.assets`
  - `architect.build.options.styles`
  - `architect.build.configurations.production.fileReplacements.replace`
  - `architect.build.configurations.production.fileReplacements.with`
  - `architect.lint.options.tsConfig`
  - `architect.lint.options.exclude`
  - `architect.test.options.jestConfig`
  - `architect.test.options.tsConfig`
  - `architect.test.options.setupFile`

### **my-app/jest.config.js**

- Update the relative paths for the following properties:

  - `preset`
  - `coverageDirectory`

### **my-app/tsconfig.app.json**

- Update the relative paths for the following properties:

  - `compilerOptions.outDir`

### **my-app/tsconfig.json**

- Update the relative paths for the following properties:

  - `extends`

### **my-app/tsconfig.spec.json**

- Update the relative paths for the following properties:

  - `compilerOptions.outDir`

### **my-app/tslint.json**

- Update the relative paths for the following properties:

  - `extends`

Comment: Do I have to have NX?

Comment: updated my answer recently. you don't need to use NX, just be aware that you need to update lots of file paths in several files (not just angular.json). Some files I listed only apply to apps created with NX. I personally recommend NX though

Comment: You've said `do not replace an absolute path with a relative path. apps/my-app becomes my-app NOT ../my-app` how so? If appliction folders are not in workspace folder anymore, then we have to go back from workspace path to main folder which is `Myproj` in this case.

Comment: I think I was confused with how you have named your folders in your question. I originally thought you were trying to move your app one level up, which is how I answered the question. Are you saying you want to move Application1 outisde of the workspace?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. Is it still possible?

Comment: `"basically get rid Workspace and have Myproj be the new workspace root"` I considered this solution, but I deluded myself that it could be done somehow differently, indicate the path node modules or something. But it seems it's impossible, so fair enough for me I got answer :) If there will be no solution soon then I'll mark yours.