# Prevent 'node_modules' directory from being repeatedly created

Tags: node.js, reactjs, wordpress, dependencies

I'm attempting to build a WordPress Block plugin and that requires the use of React.js and NPM.

Things are going along fine but the one concern I do have is that, while I already have `/node_modules/` installed in my `Documents` directory and know that the compiler will turn to parent directories until it finds the dependencies it needs, executing `npm run start` or `npm run build` will create a new `/node_modules/` directory in the directory of the project I'm working on.

I'd like to prevent this from happening for multiple reasons.  I don't want to deploy the my project to production with `/node_modules/` included and yes, I can manually remove it but that seems extremely inefficient and tedious.  Also, if every project I work on ends up with its own 300mb `/node_modules/` directory, that's just consuming tons of space on my HD for no discernible reason.

So, my question is, how do I prevent `/node_modules/` from being created in every project directory I'm working with?

Comment: Does this help . https://stackoverflow.com/a/29787493/8298248

Comment: That answer was actually where I learned you could install npm into the parent directory and that project directories in it would search upwards until they found the dependencies.   The OP mentions this `When you install your packages and add the --save arg to an npm install command` but never goes into detail about how that works.